# Pytest Python SDK Positional Arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have a directory like this

```
Platform
  -test_1.py
  -test_2.py
  Another_folder
    -test_3.py
  Test
    -start_test.py
```

Inside start_test.py, I have this code to start pytest:

```
retcode = pytest.main(["/Platform/test_*.py /Platform/Another_folder/test_*.py", "--rootdir=/Platform", "--tb=auto"])
```

But it seems like pytest cannot find any of the test and it says this:

```
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Platform
plugins: requests-mock-1.10.0, cov-4.0.0
collected 0 items
```

However, when I go to terminal, and I `cd /Platform/Test` and then run `python3 -m /Platform/test_*.py /Platform/Another_folder/test_*.py --tb=auto` there are no problems, and I get this:

```
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir:/Platform
plugins: requests-mock-1.10.0, cov-4.0.0
collected 194 items 
{bunch of test outputs}
```

How do I enter in positional arguments to manually tell pytest programmatically where to scan for the test files?